# Spring Web Flow with GWT

Tags: gwt, spring-webflow

actually I'm using Spring and GWT to build my webapp. I have a lot of forms so I want to find I pretty way handle it. Spring Webflow is a framework, that will support you by creating a lot of forms, but is it compatible with GWT? Can I combine Spring Webflow with GWT?

Maybe there is an other good/better solution, but I cann't find any information about Webfow and GWT. What is the best practise in GWT to handle multisite forms?

beste regards,
bob

Answer (score 0):

Spring Web Flow is essentially a server side controller. It fits well with frameworks that are based on MVC pattern with a controller on the server. For example, Spring MVC, JSF, Struts etc.

GWT compiles all your code to JavaScript. It essentially runs inside your browser with AJAX based interaction with the server. So, Spring Web Flow doesn't fit with this framework at all. If someone can design a client side version of Spring Web Flow that compiles in a GWT way then probably we will have a GWT compatible SWF.